# jQuery Maphilight not aligned with mouse pointer in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

we created a website using maphilight to select building floors. It worked well up till Chrome updated to 'Version 41.0.2272.101 dev-m'

Now hilighted areas are off down the mouse pointer by a small margin. It works fine in Firefox (36.0.4) so the issue seems browser specific.

Can someone advise how to fix this ?

here are the related links:

- website : http://lavenuecondos.com/en/suites/
- maphilight doc : http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Thanks

Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

I got it, it's not related only to Chrome, since I tried the developper's demo and they worked great.

Still, what I did was to change the canvas css top position (-17px)